# Excel VBA - Pictures do not display when I add Private Sub macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have images pasted (not linked) into my excel workbook. When I try to add any Private Sub macro code, the next time I open my workbook, the images come up with the message "This image can not be displayed". However, images on other sheets display correctly, and if I save the workbook on a different sheet, when it re-opens to the different sheet, only images on that sheet will not display, and images on the other sheet now display correctly. I am running Excel 2016 for Mac.

To be clear, I am not using the macros to display the images. The images have already been added into the document and are meant to always be displayed. I am simply trying to add a few lines of Private Sub code, so that my end user doesn't have to worry about a few settings before closing the workbook. This is a large workbook (which might be adding to the issues) and I want the workbook to always save in "manual" calculation mode, with calculate before save turned off.

I have tried adding "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" terms to the Private Sub, and I have tried re-inserting the pictures, as answers to other questions have suggested, but it will not fix the problem. Here is my code currently.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As  
Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I understand that I could force the workbook to save and therefore open to a sheet with no pictures to start. However I am sending this to an end user and would prefer that it look more clean than that. And mostly I am just endlessly perplexed by this issue and would love to find a more direct solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try commenting out all those lines, then uncomment one at a time.  Do the images always get that "error" on loading, or is it perhaps one line in particular that triggers it? Are there any other macros at all in the workbook?

Comment: There are other macros in the workbook, but this problem did not begin until I added the Private Sub. The problem occurs even if all of the lines are commented out. The problem is also triggered if I add ANY private sub code. I have tried to add BeforeClose and BeforeOpen events. Even adding shortcut keys as Workbook Events for the other macros will trigger the problem. I have also tried them as Public events.

Comment: To really test it, when you say "...if I add ANY private sub code", even if you *only* have a single private sub of this: `Private Sub testing() // debug.print "hi" // End Sub` the error still occurs?

Comment: I deleted my old Private Sub macro and added in the one you provided. The error did still occur.